# Contiki - Make Login Error

Tags: contiki

I am following the **Get Started with Contiki** tutorial from the Contiki web page. However, when i try to do a

```
make login
```

I get the following error

```
../../tools/sky/serialdump-linux -b115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
../../tools/sky/serialdump-linux: 1: ../../tools/sky/serialdump-linux: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make: *** [login] Error 2
```

I am using a CM5000 node which is compatible with sky platform. I am using Instant Contiki 3.0

Answer (score 2):

The **serialdump-linux** file must be replaced if you got this error. Follow the steps:

1. Download the new **serialdump-linux** file from the web page:

https://github.com/cmorty/contiki/blob/pull/serialdump/tools/sky/serialdump-linux

2. Go to the directory /home/user/contiki/tools/sky

   ```
   cd /home/user/contiki/tools/sky
   ```
3. Rename the current  ***serialdump-linux*** file with the name ***serialdump-linux.bck***
4. Copy the new ***serialdump-linux*** file in the directory /home/user/contiki/tools/sky
5. Change the permitions of the new ***serialdump-linux*** file with the command

   ```
   chmod  775 serialdump-linux
   ```
6. Now, you can use the command **make login** with no problem

If you are using another platform different than sky, then you must replace the ***serialdump-linux*** file in the directory /home/user/contiki/tools/YOUR-PLATFORM

**EDIT:** Besides, you have to install one of the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

Since **serialdump-linux** was compiled for 32 bit, and i have a 64 bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `Instant Contiki`, you should update your local working copy:

```
cd contiki
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git pull master
```

Then if you already have the `serialdump-linux` binary, recompile:

```
cd tools/sky
rm serialdump-linux
make serialdump
mv serialdump serialdump-linux
chmod +x serialdump-linux
```

Then you should be able to run without any problem.